# Make the whole BS4 Navbar (on small screens) area clickable, so anywhere you touch, it shows/hide the submenu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

Instead of just having a *button*, I want **the whole navbar area to be *touchable***. I guess it could be done just rearrenging the default BS4 navbar settings:

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="menu-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler"
        aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{site.title}}</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <div class="navbar-nav float-right text-right pr-3">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-anim.html">Animación</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-inter.html">Interacción</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-blog.html">Textual/Blog</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="acerca.html">Acerca</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You could make `#menu-navbar` clickable with JS, or you could put the entire contents of your header inside a `<button>`, but both will create lots of usability and accessibility headaches, which is why you don't often see this. Additionally, since this is pretty far outside the scope of bootstrap, you'll have to alter styling manually to have it look right.

Comment: @Toby yeah, I thought why I've never seen this implemented, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach for this is registering a listener on the `click` event of the navbar. After this, and only in the case that the button is visible (i.e. the navbar is collapsed) you can let this `click` event to toggle the collapsible element that is part of the navbar. Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#menu-navbar").on("click", () =>
    {
        // Find toggler button.
        
        var tBtn = $(this).find(".navbar-toggler");

        // Check if button is visible (navbar is collapsed). In this case
        // toggle the collapsible element.

        if (tBtn.is(":visible"))
           $(this).find(".collapse").collapse("toggle");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="menu-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NAVBAR</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
    <div class="navbar-nav float-right text-right pr-3">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">
        Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-anim.html">
        Animación
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-inter.html">
        Interacción
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="purgatorio-blog.html">
        Textual/Blog
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="acerca.html">
        Acerca
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contacto.html">
        Contacto
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```